# How to know when item has been rendered in DOM using *ngFor?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I'm displaying a list of messages using `*ngFor` and wish to apply a css class to items added to the collection *after* the list was originally rendered.

i.e. I don't want to apply the class when the view initially loads, but only when the `messages` collection gets a new item.

The source of this collection is an observable from a service which can change at any time.

```
<div *ngFor="let message of thread.messages">
    <div [class.fade-in-text]="threadWasLoaded">
        {{ message.text }}
    </div>
</div>
```

I thought I would just set a variable after I know the thread got loaded, but this has not worked.  I tried subscribing to the observable in basically every Angluar lifecycle hook.

The results are either that the css class is always applied to all list items OR I get the following error:

> Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked.

---

```
this.thread$ = 
    this.storeQuery.getThreadWithMessages(this.threadId)
        .pipe(
            map(t => this.thread = new Thread(t)),
            tap(t => this.threadWasLoaded = true)
        );
```

It's possible I'm asking the wrong question entirely.  Please let me know if my overall approach is off base. :-)

**Edit:
I've found a solution to my problem from [This Article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3417-using-no-op-transitions-to-prevent-animation-during-the-initial-render-of-ngfor-in-angular-5-2-6.htm) which approaches this in a different way by suppressing child animations on page load.**

Comment: Do you have access to the initial data in a good way? How about mapping in a true boolean on the initial objects - when this is not added to the objects coming later the property will be undefined. Then you can use ngClass  To avoid the expression-error, use an ngIf which removes the div until the initial data is set.

Comment: Modifying the DOM directly is almost always off-base. The intent of Angular is that it modifies the DOM for you. I would recommend adding a property to your object such that you can apply the class via Angular.  You can also look into animations if that’s what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys.  I just now have time to get back to this.  @LarsRødal - I do have access to the initial data, so I've tried applying a property to the objects.  The problem is that in order to set the correct value (true or false) I need to know if the item has already been rendered in the DOM, which I've been unable to determine.

Comment: @theMayer - I'm not intending to manipulate the dom directly.  Applying a property to the original items would be great, I just haven't figured out how to determine if the items has been rendered to the DOM yet to set the appropriate value.

Comment: Items are rendered to the DOM at a certain stage in the [lifecycle](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) -

Comment: Your approach to this problem is wrong. You need to have a property on your object called `isNew` that is bound to whatever css class you want (e.g. `[class.is-new]="isNew"`)

Comment: I don't disagree :-) .  I just don't know how to determine if it `isNew`.  Each time the observable emits, I get the full collection.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT 29/7-19:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptnvro
Updated Stackblitz based on comments. :)

I created a working Stackblitz-example for you based on my comment:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nn5w2u

I omitted the function for generating name here, but it is in the Stackblitz.
      objects = [];

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.fetchData();
    interval(5000).subscribe(() => this.addItem());

  }

  fetchData() {
    // creates mock data with a delay, simulating backend
    timer(2000).subscribe(() => this.objects = [{name: 'John Doe', initial: true}, {name: 'Marilyn Monroe', initial: true}])
  }

  addItem() {
    this.objects.push({name: this.generateName()});
  }
```

-

```
<ng-container *ngIf="objects.length">
<p class *ngFor="let obj of objects" [class.newItem]="!obj.initial">
  {{obj.name}}
</p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts here.  In your example this works because you hard-code the `initial` property to the items.  In my case, I have an observable that has an array property with all items.  When the observable emits a new value, I get the full collection and don't have a way to determine what may be new.  This is why I was trying to simply set a global boolean that indicates whether the items have been rendered yet.  This way I can always set the correct value after that point.

Comment: Use Object.assign to copy the full collection from the observable onto the existing data object, and my solution should still work - the initial loaded elements will have a boolean set to true (just map it in on the initial load, when the data object is undefined), while the elements coming later won't have this key.  I can probably update the example if you don't understand. 

Comment: I'm not sure that would work, but I've created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-problem-preventing-animation-on-page-load) illustrating the issue.  Also, I'm no longer in need of a solution, as I've found [This Article](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3417-using-no-op-transitions-to-prevent-animation-during-the-initial-render-of-ngfor-in-angular-5-2-6.htm) which approaches this in a different way by suppressing child animations on page load.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ptnvro - here it is, working as intended. Might be useful for other cases. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this was solved in another manner, but for future finders, this is a perfect usecase for the pairwise() operator to perform a delta operation:

```
  public  thread$ = this.dataService.thread$.pipe(
    startWith(null), // pairwise requires 2 emissions so we start it with a null
    pairwise(), // emit the last value and the current value in pairs
    map(([oThread, nThread]) => {
      if (oThread) { // only do this if there was a prior emission
        nThread.messages = nThread.messages.map(message => { // map the messages
          let isNew = false;
          if (!oThread.messages.find(m => m.id === message.id)) {
            // if they're not in the old array, they're new
            isNew = true;
          };
          return Object.assign({},message, {isNew});
        });
      }
      return nThread.messages;
    })
  );
```

and a blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-problem-preventing-animation-on-page-load-aybwz4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Nice..! I’m brand new to rxjs , so thanks for this..! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Is the `fade-in-text` class an animation? If the old items keep their `fade-in-text` class, would it cause a problem? Could you work around that?

If that's the case, just keep the `fade-in-text` class on all items. Only new items will get the animation. But Angular might not know if an item is new or not without a `trackBy` in your ngFor, so it might remove/add back the class to old items, restarting their fade-in animation.

Comment: Yes, `fade-in-text` is an animation!  Old items keeping that class is not a problem. I was trying to leverage the trackBy function and just apply the animation to all items, however, I don't want it to apply to the items initially when the page loads, so I was looking for a way to determine whether or not any of the list items have actually been rendered yet.  After that, I know that all future items should get that class.

Answer (score 0):

Create an observable with a timeout.

```
<div *ngFor="let message of thread.messages">
    <div [class.fade-in-text]="delayTrue() | async">
        {{ message.text }}
    </div>
</div>

function delayTrue() {
   return new Observable(s => setTimeout(() => (s.next(true),s.complete()));
}
```

Remove everything you did with `threadWasLoaded` and the error should go away.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'm having trouble getting to work as is. TS is complaining about missing paren.  Tried playing with it like: `return new Observable(s => setTimeout(() => {s.next(true);s.complete();}));`  should this work?  I'm seeing same behavior. :-\